# Way to many quotation marks in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, quotation-marks

I have a TableA containing brands with names, names are for example: brand1, 123, brand2, 999.

I want to select names, create button with `id=name` and pass the name to function `brandOnOff(name)`, then alert the name I passed.
When I press button "123" or "999" it works correctly. But buttons "brand1" and "brand2" don't work - they alert: `[object HTMLButtonElement]`. I think I have I problem with "" and '' and I don't know how to fix it...
When I alert(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML) I get:

```
<button id="brand1" onclick="brandOnOff(brand1)">brand1</button><button id="123" onclick="brandOnOff(123)">123</button><button id="brand2" onclick="brandOnOff(brand2)">brand2</button><button id="999" onclick="brandOnOff(999)">999</button>
```

and I think it should be like: ... `onclick="brandOnOff("brand1")"`... etc --- Quotation-mark then name then Quotation-mark

but when I try to add Quotation-marks there's an error "Unexpected end of input" and I keep messing it up.

Can somebody help me please? I'm stuck :(

Here is the code:

```
    DB.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TableA', [], function (tx, rs) {
        var brand;
        for (i = 0; i < brands; i++)
        {
            brand = rs.rows.item(i).name;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + '<button id="' + brand + '" onclick="brandOnOff(' + brand + ')">' + brand + '</button>';
        }

    }, function (tx, error) {
        console.log('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
    });
});

function brandOnOff(brandName) {
    alert(brandName);
}
```

Comment: You need to use different quotes around the brand name than around the `onclick` attribute. So if you use `onclick="..."`, then you need to use `brandOnOff('brand1')`

Comment: 1.  don't use inline event handlers, this is the root cause of your issues.  2. never use concatenation on `.innerHTML` - it converts the existing elements to HTML, then destroys them, and then has to recreate them all over again from the new HTML string.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is caused by trying to use inline event handlers, when these are generally considered obsolete and `addEventHandler` is universally supported.

You should also split out your logic somewhat into smaller testable units, that separate HTML page generation from database code:

```
// event handler - passed the clicked element in ev.target
function brandOnOff(ev) {
  alert(ev.target.id);
}

// takes an array of brand names and generates a button for each
function buildBrandButtons(brands) {
  let demo = document.getElementById('demo');

  brands.forEach(brand => {
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.id = brand;
    button.textContent = brand;
    button.addEventListener('click', brandOnOff);
    demo.addChild(button);
  });
}

// converts a result set into an array of the specified field's values
function getResultSetField(rs, field) {
  let values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; ++i) {
    values.push(rs.rows.item(i)[field]);
  }
  return values;
}

// the meat - gets the brand names, builds the buttons
function processBrands(tx, rs) {
  let brands = getResultSetField(rs, 'name');
  buildBrandButtons(brands);
}

// generic error handler
function selectError(tx, error) {
  console.log('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
}

// the actual database work
DB.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TableA', [], processBrands, selectError);
});
```

This may look like a lot more code, but each part has a specific responsibility, and some of these functions may be re-used later (e.g. `selectError`, `getResultSetField`).

NB: no nested quote marks, or indeed any that aren't around a string constant.